# Return multiple Json responses

Tags: c#, json, .net, google-places-api

I have built this API which returns JSON responses from Google place API to store/save it to the database and as this code sample shows it's List of PlaceId so I've written a For loop to loop every PlaceId and return them all then to the next point which is to post them to the database,

```
    public class portal_teilnehmerController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly _0046696KContext _context;
    private const string apiKey = @"apiKey";
    private const string fields = "&fields=address_component,rating,reviews,user_ratings_total,website";
    WebRequest request;
    WebResponse response;
    Stream data;
    StreamReader reader;
    private Task<string> responseFromServer;
    private string[] JsonResponses = { };

    public portal_teilnehmerController(_0046696KContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Getportal_teilnehmerByPlaceId()
    {
        var PlaceId = await _context.portal_teilnehmer.Select(x => x.PlaceId).ToListAsync();

        if (PlaceId == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This Portal ID not found, please be assure of your portal ID");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < PlaceId.Count(); i++)
        {

            string url = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=" + (PlaceId[i]) + (fields) + (apiKey);

            request = WebRequest.Create(url);

            response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

            data = response.GetResponseStream();

            reader = new StreamReader(data);

            string timeStamp = GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);

            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        return new JsonResult(await responseFromServer);
    }
```

but what happens when I test, it just returns me the last PlaceId response of the For loop.
Any ideas on how to return them all to maybe array and save them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas on how to return them all to maybe array and save them?

It's probably easier to use a List:

```
    var responsesFromServer = new List<string>();
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    for (int i = 0; i < PlaceId.Count(); i++)
    {

        string url = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=" + (PlaceId[i]) + (fields) + (apiKey);

        request = WebRequest.Create(url);

        response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

        data = response.GetResponseStream();

        reader = new StreamReader(data);

        string timeStamp = GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);

        responsesFromServer.Add(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
        //      ^          ^^^^^^^^^^                        ^
    }
    return new JsonResult(responsesFromServer);
    //                            ^
```

New bits underlined with a caret ^

But you could use an array, I suppose.. After all you do know how many places you're going to download..

```
    var responsesFromServer = new string[PlaceId.Count()];
    for (int i = 0; i < PlaceId.Count(); i++)
    {
        ...
        responsesFromServer[i] = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    return new JsonResult(responsesFromServer);
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect to be that easy but guess what it works like a charm, I'm so grateful for you. Thanks.
and sorry I can't vote up the answer as I'm a noob here.

Comment: It's OK.. your up votes are still recorded even though they don't show and they all suddenly apply once you hit the rep level (15 I think), for them to be applicable, so feel free to vote/ask and answer away  :)

Comment: it wasn't refreshed so I didn't saw the lastest edit, but I think the two ways are doing the same thing if I understand this well, but for some reason, I guess your code is the right way to do the thing we talk about here

Comment: They're effectively the same thing and will result in the same output JSON. Indeed internally a List uses an array anyway.. We just tend to use Lists for collections we modify and arrays for ones we dont/ As this one is being modified, I used a List. A List will also always have the "right number" of elements to contain all its data whereas if you stopped processing half way through your array would have a bunch of empty slots on the end

Comment: Yes, that what I meant **They're effectively the same thing**  but omg that's like serious trouble with my code I should follow yours now. Thanks again, and thanks for this really important informations. I voted the answer up. wish a great day to you